# What is the noun of 'to forsake'?

Tags: word-usage

What is the noun of forsaking somebody, that is, the *act* of forsaking?

Forsookenment? ;)

Comment: The gerund form of verbs, here "forsaking", can well be used as a noun.  Do you specifically want to avoid this?

Comment: Sounds like a good answer. Too obvious I guess, so you could barely believe the OP didn't think of it.

Comment: "abandonment" .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the gerund form of the verb:
"forsaking"

"She was disappointed by his forsaking [of] her."

Answer (score -1):

The adjective is "forsaken", so the noun of the verb is "forsakenness".

Comment: No, _forsakenness_ is the state of **being** forsaken, not the act of forsaking.

Comment: Agreed. The gerund form of the verb is indeed the correct answer.